# How are common free body diagrams and similar illustrations made?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, software, diagram

Over my education I've come across tons of engineering illustrations, most commonly free body diagrams and similar. I still do not know what software(s) is used to generate these. So many look very similar, and I haven't been able to find out how they're made. Does anyone know the common software(s) used for these? I've included some examples

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The images references that you have provided look like they could have been produced in LaTeX, possibly using the TikZ package.

Have a look at this example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/free-body-diagrams/ and this minimal introduction to TikZ to see if it can provide the functionality that you're after! http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf

As @Solar Mike suggested, however, plenty of diagrams are hand-drawn, and unless you are publishing a book, it's likely easier to draw these manually using a vector editor such as Inkscape.

Answer (score 2):

CAD packages, drawing packages, you can even use shapes in software like Word & Excel, but most book diagrams were drawn by hand (until computers became common) - which explains the profession of draughtsman or draughtsperson to be pc...